# rvest not able to grab html table using html_nodes("table"), despite table being on page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

We are struggling to grab the main table at [this fangraphs link](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=1&splitArrPitch=&position=B&autoPt=false&splitTeams=false&statType=team&statgroup=2&startDate=2021-07-07&endDate=2021-07-21&players=&filter=&groupBy=season&sort=9,1). Using `rvest`:

```
url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=1&splitArrPitch=&position=B&autoPt=false&splitTeams=false&statType=team&statgroup=2&startDate=2021-07-07&endDate=2021-07-21&players=&filter=&groupBy=season&sort=9,1'
table_nodes = url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('table')
table_nodes

 table_nodes
{xml_nodeset (7)}
[1] <table class="menu-standings-table"><tbody><tr>\n<td>\r\n                                            <div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\r\n                       ...
[2] <table class="menu-team-table">\n<tr>\n<td>\r\n                                        <div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\r\n                                     ...
[3] <table class="menu-team-table">\n<tr>\n<td>\r\n                                        <div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\r\n                                     ...
[4] <table>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-45-prospects-baltimore-orioles">BAL</a></td>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-34-prospects ...
[5] <table>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-30-prospects-atlanta-braves">ATL</a></td>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-49-prospects-ch ...
[6] <table>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-40-prospects-baltimore-orioles">BAL</a></td>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-38-prospects ...
[7] <table>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-27-prospects-atlanta-braves">ATL</a></td>\n<td><a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/top-41-prospects-ch ...
```

None of these 7 tables are the **main table** at the URL with all of the different team stats. `url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('div.table-scroll')` returns an empty nodeset, and `div.table-scroll` is the wrapper div that the main table is located in.

**Edit:** I guess here is the network request, but still not sure how to get API call from this. How to see the full API call for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like that table's populated by javascript (with a separate request) after the page has loaded.  Haven't done much with `rvest`, but I suspect it probably doesn't handle dynamic content.

Comment: That does seem to be the case. I am poking around in Chrome developer tools > Network > XHR trying to see if I can find something in there to scrape for this table, but cannot find where the data for the table is coming from.

Comment: I can't see the table in the page source. ps: there is a  `Export Data` button at the top-right corner of the table.

Comment: yes the export data button is convenient, however we are looking for a programatic approach to grabbing this table and doing some analysis in R. We are trying to remove the manual aspects (there are other tables to grab as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is dynamically retrieved from an API call. Switch to httr as you need to make a POST request which includes the start/end date. Also, switch to infinite in terms of returning as much data as possible, with as few calls as possible.

You want to convert the below into some form of custom function which accepts date args.

```
library(httr)
library(purrr)

headers = c(
  'user-agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0',
  'content-type' = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
)

data = '{"strPlayerId":"all","strSplitArr":[1],"strGroup":"season","strPosition":"B","strType":"2","strStartDate":"2021-07-07","strEndDate":"2021-07-21","strSplitTeams":false,"dctFilters":[],"strStatType":"team","strAutoPt":"false","arrPlayerId":[],"strSplitArrPitch":[]}'

r <- httr::POST(url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/splits/splits-leaders', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data) %>% content()

df <- map_df(r$data, data.frame)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic. How did you know to make this particular `POST` request?

Comment: I used the browser network tab (F12 Chrome) to monitor the web-traffic when pressing F5 to refresh the page. I then searched for split-leaders in the recorded activity and used preview response to check correct request.

Comment: You don't need the referer header btw. Only the content-type is actually needed.

Comment: Okay thanks. I edited question to show 2 screenshots quick. I found the network request with `split-leaders`, but not sure how to "use preview response to check correct request".